# What's the correct way of importing a Grails plugin if not mentioned in instructions

Tags: grails, plugins

I'm trying to use the methods defined in this Grails plugin after confirming that the plugin is installed correctly:

https://github.com/agorapulse/grails-open-exchange-rates/blob/master/grails-app/services/grails/plugin/openexchangerates/OpenExchangeRatesService.groovy

For all I can speculate, I add the following import line in my Controller:

```
import grails.plugin.openexchangerates
```

but the the compiler keeps nagging that it's unable to resolve the class.
I have tried all the following combinations with no avail:

```
grails.plugin.openexchangerates.*
services.grails.plugin.openexchangerates
services.grails.plugin.openexchangerates.*
```

etc.

What obvious thing am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not importing Grails plugins, btw. Just standard (groovy/java/jvm) import, but for a class that coming from a grails plugin, it's a pretty common situation.

This class have `package grails.plugin.openexchangerates`, so you can do:

```
import grails.plugin.openexchangerates.*
```

or

```
import grails.plugin.openexchangerates.OpenExchangeRatesService
```

But make sure that plugin is added to dependencies, into `BuildConfig`, as

```
compile ':open-exchange-rates:0.1'
```

Plugin readme suggests to use `runtime ':open-exchange-rates:0.1'`, but at this case compiler don't have plugin classes in classpath. You need to use `compile` scope. See more about dependency scopes: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope

Comment: I've tried all the above with no avail. Something else should be missing

Comment: Then you didn't add it to classpath. Do you have the plugin added as a dependency with scope `compile`?

Comment: the scope was actually runtime. I added the * in the end of import address and changed the scope to compile and recompiled and it worked! thanks!

Comment: oh, yes. that was the reason. with `runtime` compiled doesn't know about this class. see http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html